# Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers issue in swift header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4.1, xcode9.3

I have added swift custom uiview class file to objective c project , Inside the view there is a textview delegate is available , So when I have added I am getting the ASCII error[image]

After SWIFT_EXTENSION I tried to replace the character inside "module name" but even though it is not working , My project module name is non English character .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue ,

The issue is because of I have added extension for that uiview class , So when we add extension the class is not accepting the NON ASCII Characters .

**After removing the extension and given everything into the single class it is working fine .**